# ul and li in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of button and i would like to show different buttons if visitor is android. I tried this but of course it's not working

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf('android') > -1; 

if(isAndroid) {
  var siteurl = window.location.href;
  document.write('
<div>
<ul class='socialnbt'>\
 <li class='facebooknbt'><a href='https://www.facebook.com/username'/></li> 
 <li class='twitternbt'><a href='http://twitter.com/username'/></li>
 <li class='youtubenbt'><a href='http://www.youtube.com/user/username'/></li>
</ul>
</div>
');

} else {
  document.write('
<div>
<ul class='socialnbt1'>\
 <li class='facebooknbt1'><a href='https://www.facebook.com/username'/></li> 
 <li class='twitternbt1'><a href='http://twitter.com/username'/></li>
 <li class='youtubenbt1'><a href='http://www.youtube.com/user/username'/></li>
</ul>
</div>
');
}

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Check your quotes - they are closing prematurely

Comment: "not working" - next time please include the specific error you are getting.

Comment: Well line breaks are not valid in a string, look at the errors in the console.

Comment: @ths any suggestions? please beside the irony i would appreciate real help. thn

Answer (score 2):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which are enclosed with backticks (`) if you want Strings that span multiple lines.

If you are going to use normal Strings, you can not use the same type of quotes that you are using to enclose the String inside the String unless you escape them with a backslash (`\`) .

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf('android') > -1; 

if(isAndroid) {
  var siteurl = window.location.href;
  document.write(`Android
<div>
<ul class='socialnbt'>\
 <li class='facebooknbt'><a href='https://www.facebook.com/username'/></li> 
 <li class='twitternbt'><a href='http://twitter.com/username'/></li>
 <li class='youtubenbt'><a href='http://www.youtube.com/user/username'/></li>
</ul>
</div>
`);

} else {
  document.write(`Not android
<div>
<ul class='socialnbt1'>\
 <li class='facebooknbt1'><a href='https://www.facebook.com/username'/></li> 
 <li class='twitternbt1'><a href='http://twitter.com/username'/></li>
 <li class='youtubenbt1'><a href='http://www.youtube.com/user/username'/></li>
</ul>
</div>
`);
}

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: could you please check again the code. links in the ul socialnbt1 are getting mixed. So the facebook link shows when i click facebooknbt1 but also when i click twitternbt1.  and when i click youtubenbt1 i clicks the link of twitter tha should be clicked in button twitternbt1. the youtube link is never clicked. Is like it is not recognizing one li

Comment: @JohnGrischam What is the problem?

Comment: In the not android version button 2 receives the same link as button 1. looks like it is not recognizing one li

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems:

- JavaScript doesn't support multi-line strings unless you use [`` ` `` template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  Note this will not work in all browsers (IE and probably older versions of Android will show errors).  It's probably better to build your strings one line at a time.
- You're using `'` to quote your strings, but your strings themselves also contain `'`.  The way you have it written, the quote ends the string.  Quotes inside the string need to be escaped like `\'`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see here you just want to have different class name if the client is Android. Instead of document.write() the whole HTML snippet, a better approach would be simply use JavaScript to change the parent class and use css selectors to control the children li styles.

Example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-chwg2q

Comment: Thank you. I can do that. Could you please explain why this is a better approach. Thank you

Comment: @JohnGrischam code example added. I'm sure you'll understand why this is a better approach after reading the code.

Comment: what if i want to change also the links in android not only the style. what should i do in this case?

Comment: simply `document.querySelector('a').href = 'SOME_OTHER_LINK'`, the point is that try to avoid `document.write` as much as you can